# sheets regex formula to remove specific text from end of string

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a list of players, some of these players have "DD" or an "O" at the END of the name that id like to remove.

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "DD", "")`

can remove DD as there is no other DD however many name have the single "O" that would also be removed.

here is a sample sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HoLyoDhP8KVTrsVKIp9FxVonVa2uvK6zQ8MVco9k3U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(DD|O)$",)
```